# How to configure apache to allow overlapping locations (for svn and websvn)

Tags: apache, svn, websvn

I have an apache configuration that works for SVN DAV and WebSvn. I am currently serving DAV at http://svnserver/svn and websvn at http://svnserver/websvn.

What I would like to do is serve DAV at http://svnserver/ and websvn at http://svnserver/websvn. However, I can't get it to work because the websvn location is below the dav root.

I have two  sections, one for / and one for /websvn.  With this configuration you can't get to websvn at all becase the root location takes over. I thought I could use a regex to match for DAV but that doesn't work either:

I have tried:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!websvn/)" >
```

and

```
<Location ~ "^/(?!websvn/)" >
```

but neither work. With the regex in place the connecton gets reset when accessing /. Accessing /websvn works fine.

I read a posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665799/locationmatch-and-dav-svn) that suggests that apache does something to a request when passed through a regex and this messes up dav. It looks like this is true.

If there's anything more definitive on this, or any suggestions as to how I could get this to work ?

Comment: There's a related bug filed at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35077

Comment: what's the regex for?  sounds like it could be <Location /websvn> and <Location />  As long as the websvn comes first in the config you might be ok

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug ... rather a misconfiguration, unless the requests are being properly rewritten *before* passed onward to the PHP or webDAV module. In order to make it work, one would need to place the /websvn as topmost regex into .htaccess and exclude these request from the webDAV by adding the [L] flag... one even could load apache2 modules on demand, based on the requested location. Sorry for not providing exact syntax (at work), but the hint to place the exclusion topmost should make it work as desired.